# Stripe/Apple Pay immediately closing

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments, applepay, applepay-web

We have a web application written in React that integrates with Stripe to take payments.

When the user accesses the Apply Pay option, the popup immediately closes before they can complete the transaction.

- The domain has been added to the Apple Pay settings on Stripe
- There are no errors or logs in the javascript console to indicate an issue.
- This is using Stripe Connect
- The same page works perfectly on Google Pay

The page in question is publicly accessible here: https://whitecobalt.rendr.co.uk/pay?key=0tRvBe7q4E10230

I have recorded a screen-share video of the issue, which can be viewed here:

Has anyone else experienced this or is able to point us in the right direction, we've tried everything, and we're a bit stumped!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That usually means you didn't register the domain correctly for Apple Pay with Stripe.

On that page you are using Connect, you are trying to initialise stripe.js with the account `acct_1M1B1IQ0dY0splyg`.

So in that case you need to register the exact domain `whitecobalt.rendr.co.uk` on the connected account by making the `/v1/apple_pay/domains` API call described at https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/payment-request-button?client=html#html-js-using-with-connect , using the livemode secret key of your platform account and that domain name/account ID as params.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you - I have it working now.

It seems when you're working with Stripe Connect you need the domain in both the master Stripe account and the connected Stripe Account - then it works!